# Fetch complex data from API, create a array of objects and iterate this

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, api, next.js

I'm trying to make a array of complex objects from this:

https://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_show?id=sample-dataset-1

I want use this array of objects to create components using map()

- I used http://json2ts.com to make the type for the response:

```js
// ... other types like Tag
export type DatasetInfoResult = {
  license_title: string
  relationships_as_object: string[]
  maintainer_email: string
  tags: Tag[]
    //... all the params
}

export type DatasetInfoResponse = {
  help: string
  success: boolean
  result: DatasetInfoResult
}
```

My code:

- datasetIDs is a array of strings. This contain the dataset names, like *sample-dataset-1*
- getDataset fetch the API adress, and is ok

```js
export async function getAllDatasets() {
 
    const datasetsIDs = (await listDatasets())
    let allDatasets: DatasetInfoResult[]

    datasetsIDs.map( async id => {
        allDatasets.push( await getDataset(id) )

    })

 return allDatasets
```

Error message: *TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')*

Trying another way:

```js
export async function getAllDatasets() {
 
    const datasetsIDs = (await listDatasets())
    let allDatasets: DatasetInfoResult[]

    
    for (let i = 0; i <= datasetsIDs.length; i++ ) {
    
    const resp = ( await getDataset( datasetsIDs[i]) )
    allDatasets = [...allDatasets, resp]
    // allDatasets.push(resp)
    
  }
 return allDatasets
```

Error message: *allDatasets is not iterable*

How can I make this? What is a better way to get many data and use this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first example you're trying to push to undefined because `allDatasets` wasn't initialised with a value.

```
let allDatasets: DatasetInfoResult[] // this is undefined, so you can't push to it

datasetsIDs.map( async id => {
  allDatasets.push( await getDataset(id) )
})
```

You could try

```
let allDatasets: DatasetInfoResult[] = []

datasetsIDs.map( async id => {
  allDatasets.push( await getDataset(id) )
})
```

Comment: Thanks Rixcy, but it still `undefined`. Message: *Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.*